# Regarding Selection Of Language

Tags: node.js

I am new new to node.js but i am little curious to learn this language but if my web based application is heavy or having many calculation type of work and heavy processing then is it good language to use in that scenario.

Comment: nodejs is single threaded. all kind of heavy processing logic will block/stall the event loop, thus slowing considerably your application.

Comment: You can find a lot of articles adressing this question. take your time and do an appropriate search.

Comment: https://stackshare.io/nodejs/in-stacks - take a look here, you will find companies using node.js as their tech-stack. If you think your application would need to perform more calculations or require heavy processing than these applications, then opt for other language.

Comment: From lots of research as the node.js is not consistent what exactly does it mean?